# Trouble with Rails controller (integration?) test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testunit

I'm making my first Rails app, so this is probably basic.

In my user profiles, I want to let users add a title and description. I made them attributes of the `User` model and added this to `routes.rb`:

```
  resources :users do
    member do
      post 'update_description'
    end
  end
```

The same method (not written yet) would handle both attributes. To practice TDD, I wanted to write a test that would simply show that, if the user submits a title, then the controller saves it to the database. I thought that would be an integration test, but I couldn't get the path right. (*Should* it be an integration test?) But then, with research, I managed to write a working `post` statement in a related controller test file. Here's the controller test:

```
  test "profile submits new title and description successfully" do
    log_in_as(@user)
    get :show, id: @user
    assert_nil @user.title
    post :update_description, id: @user, params: { title: "Lorem ipsum" }
    # Next:
    # @admin.reload.title
    # assert @admin.title == "Lorem ipsum"
    # assert_template 'users/show'
    # Etc.

  end
```

This raises the following error:

```
ERROR["test_profile_submits_new_title_and_description_successfully", UsersControllerTest, 2017-10-22 21:42:52 -0400]
 test_profile_submits_new_title_and_description_successfully#UsersControllerTest (1508722972.17s)
ActionView::MissingTemplate:         ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template users/update_description, application/update_description with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
          * "/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates"
          * "/home/globewalldesk/startthis/app/views"
          * "/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/app/views"

            test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:83:in `block in <class:UsersControllerTest>'
        test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:83:in `block in <class:UsersControllerTest>'
```

I gather that this means Rails is looking for a view file and can't find one, but I don't see why `post :update_description` has it looking for a view...I thought it would be posting info without a view (I have a similar route that works the same way with no view). The `update_description` method is in the `Users` controller. I've done a lot of research but I cannot figure out what am I doing wrong. Help! TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you write test it looks as a Integration test. But I personally would advice to write a System test. Because I see you create a `update_description`member route just to update User object? Thats not necessary - your `User`resource has `edit` and `update` actions already, so you can remove that member route.

Integration testing used to check workflows and how interacts different parts of the app. While System check is for user interactions - basically you check things that user would do and see in his browser. Also it appears to me much simpler to write test in this technique (at least at this level).

So your system test would look like:

```
setup do
  log_in_as(@user) // or what ever code to visit login page and login user
end

test "profile submits new title successfully" do
  visit edit_user_path

  fill_in "Title", with: "Lorem ipsum"

  click_on "Save"

  assert_response :redirect
  follow_redirect!
  assert_select "Title", text: "Lorem ipsum"
end
```

This assumes that after user submits his form, app redirects to `user_path(@user)` (show page).

And Integration test would look something like:

```
test "profile submits new title successfully" do
  log_in_as(@user) // or what ever code to login user
  get "/user/#{@user.id}/edit"
  assert_response :success

  updated_title = "Lorem ipsum"

  patch :update, user: { id: @user.id, title: updated_title }

  assert_response :redirect
  follow_redirect!
  assert_response :success
  assert_select "Title", text: "Lorem ipsum"
end
```

Note - I haven't tested this and I use Capybara and other tools, but not Minitest. But in this simple this should work I think.

And check the [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#implementing-a-system-test) if you havent done that yet..

Comment: Wow, I was looking online a lot the last couple of days about doing JavaScript testing. One of the test frameworks I've heard about was Capybara, and here on the Rails Guides page you link to, it says, "System tests uses Capybara as base." Do you know if that's true of Rails 4.2.2, which I'm using? Anyway I'm going to try out your solution at least for the integration test. The System Test looks like it's another thing to learn (soon). Thanks!

Comment: So, here's the problem that led me to make an `update_description` route instead of relying on `Users#edit`. The user edit page (which lives at `users/<id>/edit`) has name and password. The profile page lives at `users/<id>`. I want to make it possible for the user to add profile-y type info like title, description, and receive messages. So I figured...those are `User` properties, right? But I've already got an `edit` action to handle the username and password info. So I'll just make a new route to handle the editing of User info.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I got two things wrong. First, in the integration test, I was using the wrong `post` line. This worked:

    `post "/users/#{@non_admin.id}/update_description",
         params: { title: "I am the man of constant sorrow." }`

And the other problem was that the `Users#update_description` action was supposed to load _some_ sort of view (I hadn't written the method yet!). I simply added `redirect_to user_path(@user)` and it worked!

Comment: Glad you solved it. About editing info, as you see you have many choices, Rails is quite flexible. Capybara is used by many testing frameworks, as I see. I use RSpec and it also uses Capybara. And I am pretty sure Capybara comes with default Rails instalation.